# Embed an element (video) in a p5 object

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Is there any way to embed a div in an p5 object?

I am going to insert a `video` tag into the page later. I need a div to insert it into, and I'd like to insert it into this Player object. Alternatively, is there a way for me to get the div to follow the p5 object around?

Here's my object

```
class Player {
  constructor(player) {
    this.x = player.x;
    this.y = player.y;
    this.goalX = 0;
    this.goalY = 0
    this.id = player.id;
    this.rotation = player.rotation;
    this.rgb = player.rgb;
  }

  draw() {
    fill(this.rgb.r, this.rgb.g, this.rgb.b);

    this.x = lerp(this.x, this.goalX, 0.05);
    this.y = lerp(this.y, this.goalY, 0.05);
    circle(this.x, this.y, 30);
  }
}
```

I create them like `new Player(playerFromServer)` and update its properties later

Answer (score 2):

You could create the div and modify its position by doing something like this:

```
var div = document.getElementById('#idOfYourDiv');
div.style.left = PlayerX;
div.style.top = PlayerY;
```

Take into consideration that you are changing the position of your div relative to the top-left corner.

Although an easier alternative is to use p5 to draw the video on the canvas (this is the official reference example):

Link: https://p5js.org/examples/dom-video-canvas.html

```
let fingers;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(710, 400);
  // specify multiple formats for different browsers
  fingers = createVideo(['assets/fingers.mov', 'assets/fingers.webm']);
  fingers.hide(); // by default video shows up in separate dom
  // element. hide it and draw it to the canvas
  // instead
}

function draw() {
  background(150);
  image(fingers, 10, 10); // draw the video frame to canvas
  filter(GRAY);
  image(fingers, 150, 150); // draw a second copy to canvas
}

function mousePressed() {
  fingers.loop(); // set the video to loop and start playing
}
```

And You can change the X and Y position of the video when you diplay the image. Like so:

```
image(fingers, Xposition, Yposition);
```